# Initial values for PreferenceScreen/PreferenceFragment when using PreferenceDataStore

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm implementing a preference screen which is an XML file with the PreferenceScreen tag inflated in a PreferenceFragment.  Typically this is backed by SharedPreferences, however for my particular situation we are swapping the SharedPreferences for a custom PreferenceDataStore for some of the preferences.

In the Fragment onCreate method we get the individual preferences and hook them to the PreferenceDataStore.

```
SwitchPreference pref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("my_boolean_preference");
pref.setPreferenceDataStore(dataStore);
```

This works fine except that the current value is ignored when the screen is first displayed.  How can I get the value when the screen is first displayed to be correct.  Should I put the above code somewhere other than onCreate?  Is there some refresh or rebind I should call?

Currently I'm working around the issue by manually setting the value right after calling setPreferenceDataStore.

```
pref.setChecked(dataStore.getBoolean("my_boolean_preference", false));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/use-saved-values#enable_the_data_store):

> Note: If you set a data store for a Preference after the Preference is
> attached to the hierarchy, the initial value for the Preference is not
> propagated again.

You can do this:

```
class MyFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle, rootKey: String) {
        super.onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState, rootKey)

        // set dataStore before calling setPreferencesFromResource()
        preferenceManager?.preferenceDataStore = dataStore

        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_main, rootKey)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This attaches the custom data store to all preferences. Any solution for changing the data store of individual preferences only?